# Chaining React.useEffect dependencies results in slow re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am creating a screen to "buy" crypto, and I have organized the components as in the image attached. When I change the EUR input amount I expect the calculations to be done very fast, since no API calls are involved (just basic math operations). Since I am passing the useEffect state and update function down from BuyScreen to CurrencyWidget and FeeSummary as props, I need to use (as far as I know) useEffect and a dependency on a value to make sure I have the last updated one.

The issue consists in how slow the UI is updating ([see GIF](https://gfycat.com/untidyflimsycaterpillar)), since I am changing several useEffect hooks to be sure I have all the updated values. Is there something that can be improved in my code to solve this issue?

[image: components hierarchy]

**BuyScreen.js**

```
const calculateTotalBuyTransactionAmount = (
  buySourceAmount,
  cryptoBuyPrice
) => {
  return (buySourceAmount / cryptoBuyPrice).toFixed(8);
};

const calculateSubtotal = (amount, fees) => {
  return (amount - fees).toFixed(2);
};

const BuyScreen = (props) => {
  const [buySourceAmount, setBuySourceAmount] = useState(0.0);
  const [buyDestinationAmount, setBuyDestinationAmount] = useState(0.0);
  const [feeAmount, setFeeAmount] = useState(0.0);
  const [feeSubTotalAmount, setFeeSubTotalAmount] = useState(0.0);
  const [cryptoBuyPrice, setCryptoBuyPrice] = useState(
    pricesMock[0].values.prices.EUR.buy
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setFeeAmount((buySourceAmount * 0.05).toFixed(2));
  }, [buySourceAmount]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFeeSubTotalAmount(calculateSubtotal(buySourceAmount, feeAmount));
  }, [feeAmount]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setBuyDestinationAmount(
      calculateTotalBuyTransactionAmount(feeSubTotalAmount, cryptoBuyPrice)
    );
  }, [feeSubTotalAmount]);

  console.log("Rendering BuyScreen");

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Container>
        <Content padder>
          <View>
            <CurrencyWidget
              currencyName={balancesMock.values.currencyBalances[0].name}
              currencyCode={balancesMock.values.currencyBalances[0].code}
              balance={balancesMock.values.currencyBalances[0].total}
              inputAmount={buySourceAmount}
              setInputAmount={(amount) => {
                setBuySourceAmount(amount);
              }}
              autofocus
            />
            <FeesSummary
              feeAmount={feeAmount}
              feeSubTotalAmount={feeSubTotalAmount}
            />
            <RealTimeCryptoPriceWidget
              currencyCode={balancesMock.values.cryptoBalances[0].code}
              cryptoBuyPrice={cryptoBuyPrice}
            />
            <CurrencyWidget
              currencyName={balancesMock.values.cryptoBalances[0].name}
              currencyCode={balancesMock.values.cryptoBalances[0].code}
              balance={balancesMock.values.cryptoBalances[0].total}
              inputAmount={buyDestinationAmount}
              destinationCurrency
            />
          </View>
          <View>
            <LoadingSpinner area="buy-button">
              <Button
                block
                primary-light
                style={{
                  marginBottom: 16,
                }}
              >
                <Text>Buy {balancesMock.values.cryptoBalances[0].name}</Text>
              </Button>
            </LoadingSpinner>
          </View>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

**CurrencyWidget.js**

```
const CurrencyWidget = (props) => {
  console.log("Rendering CurrencyWidget");
  return (
    <Grid>
      <Col>
        <Text notification-light>
          {props.currencyName} ({props.currencyCode})
        </Text>
        <Text label-light style={styles.balanceAmount}>
          Balance: {props.currencyCode} {props.balance}
        </Text>
      </Col>
      <Col style={{ alignItems: "flex-end", justifyContent: "flex-start" }}>
        <Item regular>
          <Input
            transactionAmount
            keyboardType="numeric"
            placeholder="0"
            editable={!props.destinationCurrency}
            autoFocus={props.autofocus}
            value={String(props.inputAmount)}
            onChangeText={(amount) => {
              console.log("amount: ", amount);
              amount === ""
                ? props.setInputAmount("0")
                : props.setInputAmount(amount);
            }}
          />
        </Item>
      </Col>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

**FeeSummary.js**

```
const FeesSummary = props => {
  const sellPageFees = () => {
    return (
      <Grid style={styles.verticalPadding}>
        <Row>
          <Col style={styles.verticalCenter}>
            <Text label-light>Subtotal</Text>
          </Col>
          <Col style={[styles.verticalCenter, { alignItems: "flex-end" }]}>
            <Text notification-light-regular>
              EUR {props.feeSubTotalAmount}
            </Text>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col style={styles.verticalCenter}>
            <Text label-light>Fees</Text>
          </Col>
          <Col style={[styles.verticalCenter, { alignItems: "flex-end" }]}>
            <Text notification-light-regular>EUR {props.feeAmount}</Text>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  };

  const buyPageFees = () => {
    return (
      <Grid style={styles.verticalPadding}>
        <Row>
          <Col style={styles.verticalCenter}>
            <Text label-light>Fees</Text>
          </Col>
          <Col style={[styles.verticalCenter, { alignItems: "flex-end" }]}>
            <Text notification-light-regular>EUR {props.feeAmount}</Text>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col style={styles.verticalCenter}>
            <Text label-light>Subtotal</Text>
          </Col>
          <Col style={[styles.verticalCenter, { alignItems: "flex-end" }]}>
            <Text notification-light-regular>
              EUR {props.feeSubTotalAmount}
            </Text>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  };
  console.log("Rendering FeeSummary");
  return props.isSellPage ? sellPageFees() : buyPageFees();
};
```

Comment: Have you tried to see how this works using a HOC kinda state management? Something like an onChange func from the parent to manage the state instead of using the useEffects so that you're directly changing the state immediately instead of waiting for React to realize it needs to re-render those components with the new data?

Edit: You could also look at using something like [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) from React and creating your own little Redux like statemanager for these components along with a context.

Comment: I think I managed through your suggestion, thanks! See the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone running in the same issue, I managed to solve by handling the state update separately from the calculations needed to update the fields, see the following code:

**BuyScreen.js**

```
<CurrencyWidget
   currencyName={balancesMock.values.currencyBalances[0].name}
   currencyCode={balancesMock.values.currencyBalances[0].code}
   balance={balancesMock.values.currencyBalances[0].total}
   inputAmount={buySourceAmount}
   setInputAmount={handleBuySourceAmount}
   autofocus
/>
```

And the handleBuySourceAmount function:

```
const handleBuySourceAmount = (amount) => {
    const _feeAmount = calculateFees(amount);
    const _subTotalAmount = calculateSubtotal(amount, _feeAmount);
    const _totalBuyAmount = calculateTotalBuyTransactionAmount(
      _subTotalAmount,
      cryptoBuyPrice
    );

    setBuySourceAmount(amount);
    setFeeAmount(_feeAmount);
    setFeeSubTotalAmount(_subTotalAmount);
    setBuyDestinationAmount(_totalBuyAmount);
  };
```